# Itext hyphenation неправильно переносит русские символы

Tags: java, кириллица, itext

Файл шрифта, который поддерживает кириллицу:

```
PBaseFont bf3 = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Pacifico-Regular.ttf", "cp1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Font font3 = new Font(bf3, 20);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setWidthPercentage(10);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("ru", "ru", 2,2));
phrase.add(new Chunk("привет мир ",font3));
table.addCell(phrase);
document.add(table);
```

**Привет мир** переносится вот так:

**Приве-т мир** - Это если делать в маленьком table.А если делать по всей странице то переносится по словам, а не по буквам, ведь можно добавить собственный перенос по буквам с помощью ? Как его лучше реализовать? И как отключить их перенос собственный перенос ?